# Encrypting Network Drives

Tags: nas, encryption, truecrypt

I have a freecom network drive (which has a usb option and a network option to connect), so it can be directly connected to a pc via usb or to a network switch via RJ45.

http://www.freecom.com/ecproduct_detail.asp?ID=4095&CatID=8020&sCatID=1146266&ssCatID=1149434
http://www.freecom.com/productsubs.asp?CatID=8020&sCatID=1146266&s=ja

I am planning to use either of the above to connect directly to my network switch so i can backup some of my computers / data to it.

Question :
Can I truecrypt this network drive and use truecrypt utility on a Local LAN computer to mount / dis mount it ?

any suggestions would be very helpful.
Kind Regards

Comment: I think this would be better suited to superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

You can certainally create a Truecrypt container on the mapped network drive and mount this. This should suit your needs.
Source [here](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=sharing-over-network)

i haven't been able to find any documentation that shows that the whole device can be encrypted and mounted, I'm not sure how turecrypt would detect it as a device. Although whole network shares can be encrypted. So I have a niggling feeling it would be possible. Quite an interesting question though, I'll be interested to see if anyone comes back with a definitive answer.

Comment: with you on most of this answer, but i don't think the whole share encrypted is going to happen with truecrypt. +1 anyway...still interested to see if someone comes up with a way